# Calibrating a wide gamut display

Tags: colors, laptop-display, visual-artifacts, calibration, color-depth

Wide gamut displays have started becoming more and more common these days and yet Windows 10 still isn't a color managed OS so I am assuming that other people might be having similar issues as well.

**Problem 1 - Over-saturated colors**

My laptop (ASUS ROG Strix GL503GE) has a TN panel with 92% NTSC coverage with a 130% sRGB color gamut leading to the colors (mostly the reds and yellows) to become over-saturated

**Problem 2 - Visual artifacts like block-y color gradient in HDR content (mostly on Netflix), complex gradients (like walls or sky) and blacks**

I know that this might not be directly tied into the color gamut but it is definitely a color depth issue.

> Relevant specs
>
> On-board graphics card - Intel 630 (hooked to the display)
>
> Dedicated graphics card - NVIDIA GTX 1050Ti
>
> Yes, I have uninstalled and reset all ASUS bloatware that might affect the color profiles or display settings
>
> Yes, I have tried different ICC profiles off the internet but none of them resolve either of the issues

[image: Intel Graphics Information Center screenshot for other helpful info about the drivers and settings]

I have scoured the internet looking for a decent solution to these problems to no avail. I am hoping this community can shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accurately calibrate a monitor is with a hardware colorimeter. The more you pay, the better they are, broadly speaking. 50 bucks won't get you far, 250 gets closer.

You might try & see if you can rent one [something I've never tried, I have my own.]

Comment: I agree and like I mentioned, I have tried using professionally calibrated ICC profiles but they don't solve the issue. Because it has to do with the OS/applications not interpreting the colors right. 100% red in sRGB is like 77% red but it is being interpreted and displayed as 100%, which is causing the over-saturation

Comment: It's no good using one made by someone else for **their** monitor - they just don't work like that. You need one for **your** monitor... & then you need apps that respect it [which I understand isn't all that straightforward in Windows].